# Caeasar Cipher with java's acm

Tags: java, acm-java-libraries

The code below encrypts a word or sentence in the way Caesar did. You put the shift value and the program takes each letter of the word/sentence and "moves" in the alphabet acoording to the shift (key) value. But this is not the problem.
I found the code on the internet and i cannot explain some of it's lines.
I know how it works but i need some specific answer about some of it's lines.
Here is the code:

```
import acm.program.*;

public class CaesarCipher extends ConsoleProgram {

public void run() {
    println("This program implements a Caesar cipher.");
    int key = readInt("Character positions to shift: ");
    String plaintext = readLine("Enter a message: ");
    String ciphertext = encodeCaesarCipher(plaintext, key);
    println("Encoded message: " + ciphertext);
}


private String encodeCaesarCipher(String str, int key) {
    if (key < 0) key = 26 - (-key % 26);
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
                ch = (char) ('A' + (ch - 'A' + key) % 26);
            }
            else {
                ch = (char) ('a' + (ch - 'a' + key) % 26);
            }
        }
        result += ch;
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

---

What exactly do those lines mean, and how do they do what they do?

```
ch = (char) ('A' + (ch - 'A' + key) % 26);
```

and

```
ch = (char) ('a' + (ch - 'a' + key) % 26);
```

Comment: Which part don’t you understand? `(char)`, math with letters, the `%` operator…?

Comment: @minitech (char) and math with letters.  the other one is the modulo

Comment: @user3129939 Did I answer your question? I'd be happy to try explaining a different way.

Comment: @trojansdestroy well,first of all i want to thank you for your time.After that,it is true that you gave me a lot of help,but could you answer that?: when you say "offset" you mean something like a start point?

Comment: @user3129939 Yes, with offset I refer to number of letters away from 'A', where 'A' is the starting point. I added an example to my answer; if you have more questions about it, feel free to comment there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those two lines behave identically, except for the fact that one applies to uppercase, and one to lowercase. I'll explain the uppercase operations here. Keep in mind that these `char` values are treated as `int`s until step 6 below.

```
ch = (char) ('A' + (ch - 'A' + key) % 26);
```

1. `ch - 'A'` gives the initial character's `int` offset from capital-A.
2. `ch - 'A' + key` increases the offset by `key`, creating the ciphered character's offset from capital-A.
3. `(ch - 'A' + key) % 26`: the modulo here ensures that the numeric value of the ciphered character is 0-25 (for the 26 letters in the alphabet), preventing alphabet "overflow." The value of that expression is now the normalized offset of the ciphered character from capital-A.
4. `'A' + (ch - 'A' + key) % 26` adds the ciphered character's offset from  capital-A to capital-A itself, resulting in the ciphered character's `int` value.
5. `(char) ('A' + (ch - 'A' + key) % 26)` casts that `int` to `char` type, resulting in the ciphered character as a `char`.

This code treats the beginning of the alphabet (capital-A) as the "starting point," from which each letter's offset is measured. The offset is the character's number of letters from 'A'.

Example: To cipher "E" with a key of 6:

1. Find the number of letters between "E" and capital-A. The ASCII code of A is 65, and the code of E is 69. To find E's offset from A, subtract `69 - 65 = 4`.
2. Add the offset and the key: `4 + 6 = 10`. This is the number of letters from A the ciphered character will be.
3. `10 % 26 = 10` (no effect because of the small starting letter + small key)
4. `'A' + 10 = 65 + 10 = 75` results in the ASCII code of the ciphered character, 75 ('K')
5. Casting 75 to `char` allows it to be treated as a character, rather than an `int`.

Comment: now that you added the example i'm pretty sure i get it more clearly and easily! thank you very much for your time!
now i understood that,i'm going to try to solve the problem in another way! keep coding

Answer (score 2):

It is converting the character to the ASCII equivalent, as denoted by the + operator (you cannot add characters, only numbers), then changing the character by a certain number of values.  The `(char)` is casting (converting) the result back to a character so you can assign it to `ch`.

'A's ASCII value is 65, and `ch` is the character currently being evaluated at position `i` in the string.  `ch = (char) ('A' + (ch - 'A' + key) % 26);` evaluates as '65 + (character's ASCII number - 65 + key) % 26'.  This result is then cast back to a character and assigned to `ch`.  The modulo (%) operator takes a number, divides it by a second number, in this case 26, and returns the remainder (5 % 6 is 5, while 7 % 3 is 1).  The second statement works the same way, but uses lowercase 'a' (97) instead of capital 'A'.

See this page for ASCII keys: http://www.asciitable.com/